# Getting the password from Wordpress to pass back to RemotePost class

Tags: php

Does anyone know how to get the uname and esp the psword from Wordpress to pass into the remotepost.class.php

eg
 private $uname = $current_user->user_login;
 private $pass = '???';

This is related to this question: [How to use XML-RPC metaWeblog.newPost properly with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695323/how-to-use-metaweblog-newpost-xmlrpc-api-properly-with-php)

Comment: Beyond the fact that you simply can not do what you are asking .. by design?

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Post says, you can't get the password. In any good system, passwords are hashed rather than encrypted. Hashing is a one-way function - you cannot un-hash a hashed password, which prevents those with access to a user database from knowing the stored passwords.

On top of this, Wordpress applies a salt to the password before hashing, so even if it was possible to un-hash the password, you'd need to know which part is the password and which part is the salt.

Comment: Just curious: given password and the stored hash can be compared, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Given the password and the salt, you can find the user with that password & salt.